# Syso shortcut doesn't work in Eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse

I have the latest version of Eclipse - Mars.
When I try to type syso and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> nothing happened, but on eclipse Luna that shortcut works. I must type sysout in Mars.

Does anyone knows how to change that?

Comment: Did you look at [this](http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/Keyboard_shortcuts_(3.0).pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and figured it out after playing around with some settings. So, here's what you should do:

1. Go to Windows->Preferences->Content Assist->Advanced
2. Check on the box saying- Java Proposals.
3. Uncheck the box saying- Java Proposals (Code Recommenders).

[image]